# touch event method on an offline osm app(the app forced closed)

Tags: android, osmdroid

This is an app for an *offline osm map*. The app works fine *without touchy class* but after adding `touchy()` class the app shuts down

```
import java.util.List;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.graphics.Canvas;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.location.LocationManager;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.MotionEvent;

public class MainActivity extends Activity implements OpenStreetMapContributorConstants{
    long start,stop;
     Context t;
     MyLocationOverlay compass;
     private MapView m_mapView;
     List overlaylist ; 

    // Default map zoom level:
    private int MAP_DEFAULT_ZOOM = 12;

    // Default map Latitude:
    private double MAP_DEFAULT_LATITUDE =  31.039109;

    // Default map Longitude:
    private double MAP_DEFAULT_LONGITUDE = 31.381073;

    private org.osmdroid.views.MapController mMapController;
    int mIncr = 10000;

     @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        // Specify the XML layout to use:
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);       
        m_mapView =(MapView) findViewById(R.id.mapview);
        List<Overlay> overlaylist = m_mapView.getOverlays();
        touchy t =new touchy();
        overlaylist.add(t);



         compass =new MyLocationOverlay(MainActivity.this,m_mapView);
         overlaylist.add(compass);
        // Setup the mapView controller:
        m_mapView.setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
        m_mapView.setMultiTouchControls(true);
        m_mapView.setClickable(true);
        m_mapView.setUseDataConnection(false);
        m_mapView.getController().setZoom(MAP_DEFAULT_ZOOM);
        m_mapView.getController().setCenter(
            new GeoPoint(MAP_DEFAULT_LATITUDE, MAP_DEFAULT_LONGITUDE));
        m_mapView.setTileSource(TileSourceFactory.MAPNIK);
        LocationManager locationManager = (LocationManager)         getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
        GeoPoint gPt0 = new GeoPoint(31.039109, 31.381073);
        GeoPoint gPt1 = new GeoPoint(gPt0.getLatitudeE6()+ mIncr, gPt0.getLongitudeE6());
        GeoPoint gPt2 = new GeoPoint(gPt0.getLatitudeE6()+ mIncr, gPt0.getLongitudeE6() + mIncr);
        GeoPoint gPt3 = new GeoPoint(gPt0.getLatitudeE6(), gPt0.getLongitudeE6() + mIncr);
        mMapController = m_mapView.getController();

        mMapController.setCenter(gPt0);

        PathOverlay myPath = new PathOverlay(Color.RED, this);
        myPath.addPoint(gPt0);
        myPath.addPoint(gPt1);
        myPath.addPoint(gPt2);
        myPath.addPoint(gPt3);
        myPath.addPoint(gPt0);
        m_mapView.getOverlays().add(myPath);
    }


       @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        compass.disableCompass();
        super.onPause();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        compass.getMyLocation();
        compass.enableMyLocation();
        compass.runOnFirstFix(new Runnable(){
               public void run() {
               // First time: removes the circle and draws a dot.
               // Second time: removes the circle and dot, and draw a new dot. 
               m_mapView.getOverlays().clear();
               m_mapView.getOverlays().add(compass);
               m_mapView.postInvalidate();
               }

        });
        compass.enableCompass();
        super.onResume();
        }
    class touchy extends Overlay{



        public touchy() {
            // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
            super(t);
        }

        public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent e,MapView m){
            if(e.getAction() ==MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN){
                start = e.getEventTime();
            }if(e.getAction() ==MotionEvent.ACTION_UP){
                stop = e.getEventTime();
            }if(stop - start >3000){
                AlertDialog alert =new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this).create();
                alert.setTitle("Enter the street Condition");
                alert.setMessage("you must enter the condition ");
                alert.setButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                    }
                });
                 alert.setButton2("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                    }
                });
                 alert.setButton3("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                    }
                });
                 alert.show();
                 return true;
            }
            return false;

        }

        @Override
        protected void draw(Canvas arg0, MapView arg1, boolean arg2) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

    }

}
```

### 03-11 14:46:24.775: D/TextLayoutCache(3156): Using debug level: 0 - Debug Enabled: 0

03-11 14:46:24.905: D/AndroidRuntime(3156): Shutting down VM
03-11 14:46:24.905: W/dalvikvm(3156): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x2b542210)
03-11 14:46:24.905: E/AndroidRuntime(3156): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
03-11 14:46:24.905: E/AndroidRuntime(3156): java.lang.NullPointerException
03-11 14:46:24.905: E/AndroidRuntime(3156):     at org.osmdroid.views.overlay.OverlayManager.onDraw(OverlayManager.java:107)
03-11 14:46:24.905: E/AndroidRuntime(3156):     at org.osmdroid.views.MapView.dispatchDraw(MapView.java:818)
03-11 14:46:24.905: E/AndroidRuntime(3156):     at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:2989)
03-11 14:46:24.905: E/AndroidRuntime(3156):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:2593)
03-11 14:46:24.905: E/AndroidRuntime(3156):     at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:2989)
03-11 14:46:24.905: E/AndroidRuntime(3156):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:2593)
03-11 14:46:24.905: E/AndroidRuntime(3156):     at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:2989)
03-11 14:46:24.905: E/AndroidRuntime(3156):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:2593)
03-11 14:46:24.905: E/AndroidRuntime(3156):     at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:2989)
03-11 14:46:24.905: E/AndroidRuntime(3156):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:2593)
03-11 14:46:24.905: E/AndroidRuntime(3156):     at android.view.View.draw(View.java:11085)
03-11 14:46:24.905: E/AndroidRuntime(3156):     at android.widget.FrameLayout.draw(FrameLayout.java:462)
03-11 14:46:24.905: E/AndroidRuntime(3156):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.draw(PhoneWindow.java:2145)
03-11 14:46:24.905: E/AndroidRuntime(3156):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.draw(ViewRootImpl.java:2026)
03-11 14:46:24.905: E/AndroidRuntime(3156):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1634)
03-11 14:46:24.905: E/AndroidRuntime(3156):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.handleMessage(ViewRootImpl.java:2442)
03-11 14:46:24.905: E/AndroidRuntime(3156):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
03-11 14:46:24.905: E/AndroidRuntime(3156):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
03-11 14:46:24.905: E/AndroidRuntime(3156):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4441)
03-11 14:46:24.905: E/AndroidRuntime(3156):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
03-11 14:46:24.905: E/AndroidRuntime(3156):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
03-11 14:46:24.905: E/AndroidRuntime(3156):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:784)
03-11 14:46:24.905: E/AndroidRuntime(3156):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:551)
03-11 14:46:24.905: E/AndroidRuntime(3156):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
 ##

Comment: And what was the stack trace when it force closed?  You need to learn how to read a stack trace...

Comment: Your constructore for touchy passes t to supper but at construction time t want yet be set....  Not at all sure what your trying to do but it looks dodgy.